# I'm getting (Request failed with status code 500)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I'm trying to post with an express api, but im getting:-

```
Error: Request failed with status code 500
at e.exports (createError.js:16)
at e.exports (settle.js:17)
at XMLHttpRequest.p.onreadystatechange (xhr.js:61)
```

I'm using nodemailer and mailgun to send this form to an email, I have two forms that im trying to send, one forms and its api are working perfectly, but im getting an error when sending the enquiry form.

EnquiryForm.js

```
class EnquiryForm extends Component {
state = {
    companyname: '',
    name: '',
    address: '',
    postCode: '',
    country: '',
    city: '',
    email: '',
    telefon: '',
    message: '',
    payment: '',
    shipping: '',
    cart: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dataArr')),
    errors: {}
}
/**            cart: this.state.cart */
onFormSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ errors: {} })
    const enquiryData = {
        companyname: this.state.companyname,
        name: this.state.name,
        email: this.state.email,
        telefon: this.state.telefon,
        message: this.state.message,
        address: this.state.address,
        postCode: this.state.postCode,
        country: this.state.country,
        city: this.state.city,
        payment: this.state.payment,
        shipping: this.state.shipping,
    }

    console.log(enquiryData);

    await axios.post('/enquirypost', enquiryData)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            this.setState({ errors: err.response.data })
        })
}

changeHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    })
}
render() {
    const productArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dataArr'));
    const { errors } = this.state;
    return (
        <div className="EnquiryFormBackground" style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
            <Card className="Enquiry-Form-Box" style={{ marginBottom: '4%' }}>
                <div className="Enquiry-Form-Box-top" style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                    <span className="EnquiryFormTitle">PRODUCT LIST</span>
                    {productArray.map(d => (
                        <Card className="EnquiryProductRow" style={{ margin: '2% 2%' }} key={d.Heading}>
                            <div className="productCellF">
                                <img
                                    src={d.Img}
                                    alt='Product-image'
                                    className='imgCellF' />
                                <p className="textCellF">{d.Heading}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="tableCellF">
                                <p className="textCellF">&times;{d.Quantity === undefined ? 1 : d.Quantity}</p>

                            </div>
                            <div className="tableCellF">
                                <p className="textCellF">€{d.IngPrice}</p>
                            </div>
                        </Card>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </Card>
            <Card className="Enquiry-Form-Box">
                <div className="Enquiry-Form-Box-top" style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                    <span className="EnquiryFormTitle">ENQUIRY FORM</span>
                </div>
                <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                    <TextField
                        classes={{ margin: ' 2% 10%' }}
                        className="Enquiry-Form-Input"
                        id="standard-secondary"
                        label="Firmenname"
                        color="primary"
                        name="companyname"
                        type="text"
                        onChange={this.changeHandler}
                        helperText={errors.companyname}
                        error={errors.companyname ? true : false}
                        required
                    />
                    <TextField
                        className="Enquiry-Form-Input"
                        id="standard-secondary"
                        label="Name"
                        color="primary"
                        name="name"
                        type="text"
                        onChange={this.changeHandler}
                        helperText={errors.name}
                        error={errors.companyname ? true : false}
                        required
                    />
                    <TextField
                        className="Enquiry-Form-Input"
                        id="standard-secondary"
                        label="Adresse"
                        color="primary"
                        name="address"
                        type="text"
                        onChange={this.changeHandler}
                    />
                    <TextField
                        className="Enquiry-Form-Input"
                        id="standard-secondary"
                        label="Postleitzahl"
                        color="primary"
                        name="postCode"
                        type="text"
                        onChange={this.changeHandler}
                    />
                    <Select
                        className="Enquiry-Form-Input"
                        native
                        label="Land"
                        color="primary"
                        name="country"
                        onChange={this.changeHandler}
                        helperText={errors.country}
                        error={errors.companyname ? true : false}
                        required
                    >
                        {countryList.getNames().map(e => (
                            <option key={e}>{e}</option>
                        ))}
                    </Select>
                    <TextField
                        className="Enquiry-Form-Input"
                        id="standard-secondary"
                        label="Stadt"
                        color="primary"
                        name="city"
                        type="text"
                        onChange={this.changeHandler}
                    />
                    <TextField
                        className="Enquiry-Form-Input"
                        id="standard-secondary"
                        label="E-Mail"
                        color="primary"
                        name="email"
                        type="email"
                        onChange={this.changeHandler}
                        helperText={errors.email}
                        error={errors.companyname ? true : false}
                        required
                    />
                    <TextField
                        className="Enquiry-Form-Input"
                        id="standard-secondary"
                        label="Telefon"
                        color="primary"
                        name="telefon"
                        type="text"
                        onChange={this.changeHandler}
                    />
                    <TextField
                        className="Enquiry-Form-Input"
                        id="standard-secondary"
                        label="Ihre Nachricht"
                        color="primary"
                        name="message"
                        type="text"
                        onChange={this.changeHandler}
                        variant="outlined"
                        multiline
                        rows={4}
                    />
                    <div className="Enquiry-Form-Box-top">
                        <span className="EnquiryFormTitle">SHIPPING</span>
                    </div>
                    <RadioGroup
                        className="Enquiry-Form-Input"
                        aria-label="shipping"
                        name="shipping"
                        onChange={this.changeHandler}
                        helperText={errors.shipping}
                        error={errors.companyname ? true : false}>
                        <FormControlLabel className="EnquiryFormRadioBtn" value="DHL" control={<Radio />} label="DHL" />
                        <FormControlLabel className="EnquiryFormRadioBtn" value="Spedition" control={<Radio />} label="Spedition" />
                    </RadioGroup>
                    <div className="Enquiry-Form-Box-top">
                        <span className="EnquiryFormTitle">PAYMENT</span>
                    </div>
                    <RadioGroup
                        className="Enquiry-Form-Input"
                        aria-label="payment"
                        name="payment"
                        onChange={this.changeHandler}
                        helperText={errors.payment}
                        error={errors.companyname ? true : false}>
                        <FormControlLabel className="EnquiryFormRadioBtn" value="VorkasseWir teilen Ihnen die Gesamtkosten inkl. Versand mit und Sie überweisen dann per Vorkasse" control={<Radio />} label="VorkasseWir teilen Ihnen die Gesamtkosten inkl. Versand mit und Sie überweisen dann per Vorkasse" />
                        <FormControlLabel className="EnquiryFormRadioBtn" value="PaypalWir teilen Ihnen die Gesamtosten inkl. Versand mit und Sie überweisen dann mit Paypal" control={<Radio />} label="PaypalWir teilen Ihnen die Gesamtosten inkl. Versand mit und Sie überweisen dann mit Paypal" />
                    </RadioGroup>
                    <Button
                        variant="contained"
                        color="primary"
                        type="submit"
                        className="EnquiryFormBtn">
                        <span className="EnquiryFormBtnTitle">
                            Submit
                        </span>
                    </Button>
                </form>
            </Card>
        </div >
    )
}
 }

export default EnquiryForm
```

I'm not sure if its a problem with the backend or frontend

this is my express api:-

```
app.post('/enquirypost', (req, res) => {
//SENDING EMAIL
const data = {
    companyname: req.body.companyname,
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    telefon: req.body.telefon,
    message: req.body.message,
    address: req.body.address,
    postCode: req.body.postCode,
    country: req.body.country,
    city: req.body.city,
    payment: req.body.payment,
    shipping: req.body.shipping
};
console.log(data);


const { valid, errors } = enquiryCheck(data);
if (!valid) return res.status(400).json(errors);

const html = `
    <h3>Contact Details</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>company name: ${data.companyname}</li>
        <li>name: ${data.name}</li>
        <li>email: ${data.email}</li>
        <li>telefon: ${data.telefon}</li>
        <li>address: ${data.address}</li>
        <li>postCode: ${data.postCode}</li>
        <li>country: ${data.country}</li>
        <li>city: ${data.city}</li>
        <li>payment: ${data.payment}</li>
        <li>shipping: ${data.shipping}</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Message</h3>
    <p>${data.message}</p>
`;

console.log(req.body);
sendEnquiry(data.email, data.message, html, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Error' })
    } else {
        res.json({ message: 'Email Sent!!!' })
    }
})
```

})

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP 500](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) means internal server error;
and the `api` is responsible for handling that; it could be front-end (you) sending a malformed request and they didn't handle that case which raised an exception in server or there is actually a logical error on back-end side needed to be fixed; anyway you shouldn't receive `500` status from a server even if you are sending malformed request.

Comment: I added my express backend